# LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder header verification

Tags: netty

I'm trying to use LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder to decode a packet with a two byte header (sync bytes) followed by packet length on a noisy line. Is there a way I can verify the header is correct and skip the byte(s) if they are not?